# Scraping sports data frames

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

So my issue here is that I want to scrape the pitcher table and the batter table separately. When I use the selector gadget, both the pitcher and batting table uses the ".has-right-shadow". I tried to pull the tables, with the code I have, but it says no data available.

```
library(rvest)

pitcher_url <- 'https://www.rotowire.com/baseball/stats.php'
pitcher_stats <- read_html(pitcher_url)

pitcher_df <- html_nodes(pitcher_stats,".has-right-shadow")
pitcher_table <- html_text(pitcher_df)

View(pitcher_table)
```

Comment: The easier thing, if possible, is just to download the csv file provided at the bottom of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Data is easily retrieved via querystring as json. Just alter the pos (position) param in the querystring.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)

batters <- jsonlite::read_json('https://www.rotowire.com/baseball/tables/player-basic-stats.php?pos=B&league=3&season=2021&filter=0')
pitchers <- jsonlite::read_json('https://www.rotowire.com/baseball/tables/player-basic-stats.php?pos=P&league=3&season=2021&filter=0')

df_batters <- map_dfr(batters, data.frame)
df_pitchers <- map_dfr(pitchers, data.frame)
```